navigate through table recordset
My English Crash Course program requires that the user navigate to the next/previous first and last record until the end
of the table by clicking buttons that say move next/previous last/first. this code always bring the first
and the next row every time i press the button what should I change
in this code to enable this?
import kivy

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '500')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import sqlite3
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen

class Firstwindow(Screen):
pass
class Secondwindow(Screen):
pass
class Thirdwindow(Screen):
def getSingleRows(self):

connection = sqlite3.connect('book.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
print("Connected to database")

sqlite_select_query = """SELECT question FROM advanced"""
cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
print("Fetching single row")
record = cursor.fetchone()

self.ids.q.text = str(record)
print(record)

print("Fetching next row")
record = cursor.fetchone()
print(record)

cursor.close()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
def screen_manager_method(self):
pass
class CrashCourse(App):
def build(self):
Builder.load_file("crashcourse.kv")
return WindowManager()
if __name__ == '__main__':
CrashCourse().run()`

` crashcourse.kv

self.ids.q.text = str(record)


self.ids.q.text = str(record)


<WindowManager>:
     Firstwindow:
     Secondwindow:
     Thirdwindow:
<Firstwindow>:
     ``canvas:
      Rectangle:
           source:"down.jpg"
           size: self.size
 name: "home_screen"
 id: home_screen
 Button:
      id: b1
      text: 'Beginner'
      color:"purple"
      pos:200,300
      size_hint:(0.2,0.1)
      on_release:
           app.root.current="game_screen"
 Button:
      id: b2
      text:" Inermediate"
      color:"purple"
      pos:200,230
      size_hint:(0.2,0.1)
 Button:
      id: b3
      text:"Advanced"
      color:"purple"
      pos:200,160
      size_hint:(0.2,0.1)
      on_release:
           app.root.current="menu_screen"

 <Secondwindow>:
 name: "menu_screen"
 id: menu_screen
 Label:
      text:"this is screen two"
<Thirdwindow>:
 name: "game_screen"
 id: game_screen
 GridLayout
      
      cols:2
      Label:
           text:"first checkbox"
      CheckBox:
           group:"mygroup"
           on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"first checkbox")
      Label:
           text:"second  radio button"
      CheckBox:
           group:"mygroup"
           on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"second radio button")
      Label:
           text:"third radio button"
      CheckBox:
           group:"mygroup"
           on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"third radio button")
      Button:
           
           text:"Move Next"
           on_press: root.getSingleRows()`

